# How to pass props to Actions.replace react-native-router-flux

Tags: reactjs-flux, react-native-router-flux

**Version
Tell us which versions you are using:**

```
react-native-router-flux v4.0.0-beta.28
react-native v0.52.2
```

Tried the following...

`Actions.replace({ key: tabKey, props: tabPage });
Actions[key]({ type: ActionConst.REPLACE, tabPage: tabPage })`

and several variations there of

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to try the most recent version - but if that's not possible, move to the last beta that was still using `react-navigation` 1.5 - there is a branch for that version only now (`4.0.0-beta`) and then use the `execute` method.

```
Actions.execute('replace', tabKey, { tabPage });
```

And I believe the two examples you showed are not correct too, but I might be wrong, the number of changes during the work in this beta version was huge, but according to the code/API docs, this is the way you were supposed to be doing it:

```
Actions.replace(tabKey, { tabPage });

// or 

Actions[tabKey]({ tabPage }); // and use type={ActionsConst.REPLACE} on your `Scene`
```

Answer (score 0):

you most use `Actions.replace('tab name');` and this work